# Does every continuous mapping on $S^1$ have a fix point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is the statement is true or false?

> Let $S^{1} = \{(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \ : \ x^2+y^2=1\}$. Let $f : S^{1} \to S^{1}$ be a continuous function. Then, there always exists $p \in S$ such that $f(p) = p$.

I was thinking that this $S^{1}$ is a unit circle, so $S$ will compact as homeomorphism to $[0,1]$. I also know that continuous image of compact set is compact. By the intermediate theorem there always exists $p \in S^{1}$ such that $f(p) = p$. so my answer is true and statement is true.

Comment: What if $f(x, y) = (-x, -y)$?

Comment: what does the sentence "so $S$ will compact as homeomorphism to $[0,1]$" mean?

Comment: No, that isn't what the intermediate value theorem says.

Comment: What about $f(x,y)=(-x,-y)$?

Comment: Any rotation function is basically a counter-example, in addition to the 180-degree rotation provided by Francesco Polizzi.

Comment: every non trivial rotation of the circle has no fixed points

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 4):

The intermediate value theorem tells you something about functions **on an interval**. $S$ is not an interval, so the theorem is useless.

---

In fact, the statement is false. Think about mappings $f$ which "shift" the circle a little (for example, move every point by a constant angle in a clockwise direction). For example, shifting the point by $180$ degrees would make the function $f(x,y)=(-x,-y)$.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers show, by construction of a counterexample, that the statement is false.

I'll show that your answer is false and your proof is invalid, because there are many closed and bounded sets that are not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, and $S^1$ is one of them.

The one point set $\{x\}$ is closed and bounded, but it is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$: there is not even any bijection between $[0,1]$ and $\{x\}$.

The set $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ is closed and bounded, but it is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ because $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ is not connected, $[0,1]$ is connected, and two homeomorphic spaces are either both connected or both disconnected.

The circle $S^1$ is closed and bounded but it is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. Here are two ways to prove this.

First, $S^1$ has the following simple property: removing any point from $S^1$ leaves a subspace homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ which is connected. Furthermore, if two spaces are homeomorphic to each other, and if one space has this property, then the other space also has this property.  But removing the point $\frac{1}{2}$ from $[0,1]$ leaves the subspace $[0,\frac{1}{2}) \cup (\frac{1}{2},1]$ which is disconnected.

Second, the fundamental group $\pi_1([0,1])$ is trivial but the fundamental group $\pi_1(S^1)$ is nontrivial, and the fundamental groups of two homeomorphic spaces must be isomorphic.

Comment: thanks u so much @Lee mosher , now i have understand fully  and u also have  written in a very ,,,,,simple  way which is very easy to understand ..once again thanks u

Answer (score 0):

For every $\theta\in\mathbb R\setminus2\pi\mathbb Z$, the map$$\begin{array}{rcccl}r_\theta\colon&S^1&\longrightarrow&S^1\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&\bigl(\cos(\theta)x-\sin(\theta)y.\sin(\theta)x+\cos(\theta)y\bigr)&=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}.(x,y)\end{array}$$is a continuous map from $S^1$ into itself without fixed points. Therefore, there are uncountably many counter-examples to your statement.

Comment: i m not  getting the the line  angle belong  R / 2piZ@ jose carlos santos

Comment: @lomberlego I have no idea about what you mean by that.

Comment: i mean  that how it can be possible that  S map S withouts a fixed point,,,im not getting line  ,,,according to the theorem of intermediate..@ jose carlos santos

Comment: @lomberlego Are you talking about the intermediate value theorem? That's a theorem about functions defined on *intervals* and $S^1$ is not an interval. Another thing: you will got no more answers from me unless you write complete sentences written in plain English.

Comment: My english is   weak  ,,,,, but ok  i know  that S is closed and bounded becoz  S is a unit circle. so S  will be homeomorphism to [0,1].....because [0,1] is closed and bounded  according to  hein borel theorem,,,@ jose Carlos santos

Comment: Just because $S^1$ and $[0,1]$ are both closed and bounded, it does not follow that they are homeomorphic to each other. See my full answer.