# Which of the following statements are correct? (topology)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

consider $S^1 =\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 =1\}$ ,   $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2  \leq 1\}$  and $E = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 2x^2 + 3y^2 \leq 1\}$

Which of the following statements are
true?

a. If $f : D \to S^1$  is a continuous mapping, then there exists $x \in S^1$ such that $f(x)=x$.

b. If $f: S^1 \to S^1$ is a continuous mapping, then there exists $x \in S^1$ such that $f(x)=x$.

c. If $f : E \to E$ is a continuous mapping, then there exists $x \in E$ such that $f(x) = x$.

i was using the intermediate theorem, that  from my point of view , all option a b and c are correct by intermediate theorem.  But im doubting about my answer.

If anbody help me i would be very thankful to him.

Comment: Have you considered rotations of $S^1$?

Comment: how rotation is possible pliz explain me @ tyrone

Comment: Rotate the circle $S^1$ about its center through an angle $A$ where $A\in (0,2\pi).$  For example, with $A=\pi$ we have $f((u,v))=(-u,-v)$ and observe that $u^2+v^2=1\implies (u,v)\ne (0,0)\implies (u,v)\ne (-u,-v)$.

Comment: thanks @daniel wainfleet

Answer (score 2):

a. Since $S^1\subset D$, the statement is true, by [Brouwer's fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).

b. You have already asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396617/does-every-continuous-mapping-on-s1-have-a-fix-point), and so you know now (or should know) that the statement is false. Just consider a non-trivial rotation.

c. The statement is true, again by Brouwer's fixed-point theorem.

Comment: Thanks @ jose carlos santos ,,but i need a proper explanation

Comment: @lomberlego Since I made three statements, you will have to be more specific.

Comment: Is there an elementary proof of the special case of Brouwer' s fixed-point theorem when the range is $S^1$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Brouwer' s fixed-point theorem doesn't hold for $S^1$.

Comment: What I meant was the special case of a continuous $f:D\to S^1,$ as opposed to the general case of a continuous $f:D\to D.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I just used the fact that, since $S^1\subset D$, every function from $D$ into $S^1$ is automatically a function from $D$ into itself.

Comment: I know. I was wondering if the special case has an easier or more elementary proof. I like your answer.